# Socket.IO HTTP - How to Secure the Configuration

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm running Socket.IO with node.js behind nginx and only proxing through the required domain. Its a PHP site and all the security in the site is done with PHP.

For Socket.IO users authenticate by passing their UserID as shown below:

```
  iosocket.on('connect', function () {
    iosocket.emit('userid', '1000015349');
```

This works fine but I'm interested to know if there are other measures I can impliment to further secure this configuration.

Note: I'm not using SSL because I've heard mixing a HTTP site with HTTPS websockets isn't the best way to go and will cause issues in some browsers like firefox.

Could cookies, tokens etc help? I could put a unique token into the browser DOM post login that could be used to authenticate the connection or a cookie if that is better.

thx

Comment: If you site security rely on php sessions, you may like to use those php session data in you node.js application. In some way (have no idea how and where do you store sessions).

Comment: I store php session data in memcached... is it really possible to do node.js/socket.io authentication from these php sessions? have you doe this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, data is data. You only need to decode it and link session id with string key php uses to store session data. I'd implement ([SessionHandler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php)) and assign a custom session handler at php's entering point. At `public bool write ( string $session_id , string $session_data )` i'd link SID with $session_id param (note that SID != $session_id param, using files as save handler, dunno what's with memcache or redis or other cache save handler).
At node.js entering point I'd read cookies to find out SID, retrieve encoded session data string from session storage, decode it (lookup here at stackoverflow -- there are some javascript implementation of php session data encoders\decoders) and use in my node.js application.

Actually, that's how i do it at one of my projects.